# trying to print a square of X's and Y's using nested for loops

Tags: java, nested-for-loop

Input:

```
3
7
4
```

Output:

```
XXXY
XXYY
XYYY

XXXXXXXY
XXXXXXYY
XXXXXYYY
XXXXYYYY
XXXYYYYY
XXYYYYYY
XYYYYYYY

XXXXY
XXXYY
XXYYY
XYYYY
```

I have an idea that involves 2 for loops nested in another for loop that would look something like:

```
  String ret = "";
  for (int row = 0; row < size; row++) //size is the input
  {
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
      ret += "X";
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < size; col++)
    {
      ret += "Y";
    }
    ret += "\n";
  }
  return ret;
```

This code would output:

```
XXXYYY
XXXYYY
XXXYYY

XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY
XXXXXXXYYYYYYY

XXXXYYYY
XXXXYYYY
XXXXYYYY
XXXXYYYY
```

I can't really figure out how to get this working, any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Your inner loop needs to change from row to row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the < from the third for loop to <= and change the size argument to the iterative row (or size-row for the inverse)

```
String ret = "";
for (int row = 0; row < size; row++){
  for (let col = 0; col < size-row; col++){
    ret += "X";
  }
  for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++){
    ret += "Y";
  }
  ret += "\n";
}
return ret;
```